# There should be a way to manually invite users without enough rep to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, new-users

I regularly see postings from new users that don't quite fit the criteria of the relevant site.  In many cases, the posts are commented on and downvoted/closed, but the user simply never comes back to respond.  But in other cases, the user is obviously invested in their question, but doesn't agree with or understand the position of the community regarding their post.  [Here's a recent example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106757/list-of-dungeon-requirements).

Since argumentative problematic posts get so much attention from regular high-rep users, they tend to generate a lot of downvotes as well; this harms any chance the new asker has of gaining the 20 rep required to join the chat and have a more personal discussion.

In instances where a new user isn't fully understanding why their question is inappropriate, I feel like it would be nice if someone (a site moderator perhaps) had the ability to manually permit them to participate in chat temporarily even if they don't have the rep required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This already exists. Room owners can go to the room's access tab and add users to the explicit write access section:

[image: Even when this room is read-only or their reputation is too low, these users will be able to talk in this room.]

Comment: I think this only works for moderators, regular users can't circumvent the reputation limit that way.

Comment: @MadScientist I see the same message even on chat.meta where I'm not a mod, but that does sound familiar; the text might be wrong for non-mods

Comment: @MichaelMrozek are you aware of the reasoning for making this ability available only to moderators and not room owners? It seems unnecessarily restrictive and makes it hard to help new users (my current situation).

Comment: The answer is misleading, OP here is not asking about moderator abilities.