# Error with explicit chat write access for new users

Tags: bug, chat, new-users

This is obviously a spam precaution but I think the wording might be misleading and considered for revising. Here is the issue:

I was chatting with a user in comments when I get that familiar message suggesting to move the comments to chat. I click it and get the following message:

[image: Moving to chat failed]

I realized that it is because the user doesn't have 20 rep, like the chat site states. I attempt to create a chat and give the user explicit write access. In the description for write access it says

> "Even when this room is read-only or their **reputation is too low**,
>   these users will be able to talk in this room."

This, of course, made me try to add them to explicit write access. However, when I do I get the following error:

[image: User must have 20 rep to talk]

What I propose is to either update the text in the chat access control panel **or** allow any user to chat regardless of rep *if* they are given explicit write access.

Comment: Dupicate of either http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153417/if-users-with-20-rep-cant-chat-why-does-so-nag-me-to-move-comment-threads-to?rq=1 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169028/there-should-be-a-way-to-manually-invite-users-without-enough-rep-to-chat?rq=1

Comment: You need a shiny diamond to do that.

Comment: Not a duplicate since I am not talking about the actual message about moving users, rather the wording on the chat dashboard.

Comment: @MatthewR. Was there any resolution to this? I just ran into this trying to help a new user (who are the ones that really need chat for help usually). There are several topics on this that keep getting closed. I don't see the logic in only giving mods the power to provide write access. An owner should be enough.

Comment: To my knowledge nothing has been resolved with this issue. I have tried this again since writing this original post and still no luck. I have had to either add the user on a chat service or continue writing comments on the question.